# What does the idiom 'It is noon in New York' mean in Chicago?

Tags: american-english, north-american-english

I do not have a context for the idiom. All I know it is from/related to Chicago. I did not find this idiom online.

Comment: If you can't find it online are you sure it's an idiom? I'd expect for it to be part of something longer, e.g. "When it's 11am in Chicago, it is noon in New York" or "When it is noon in New York, it's 5pm in London".

Comment: Yes, it was in a questionnaire (Do you know the idiom:. ..). Though, with no answer.

Comment: These kind of time zone sayings are usually used, tongue-in-cheek, to justify doing something before it’s deemed generally acceptable.  In Chicago it might be too early to have a drink, but you could say, “But it’s noon in New York”.  More typically, though, it’s “But it’s happy hour somewhere (in the world)”

Comment: Because it was asked whether you know the idiom "..." and lived in Chicago. No further context apart from the Chicago clue.

Comment: The answer has been revealed. It is a specific regional version of "it is 5 o'clock somewhere". So as far as I know, @Jim had the correct answer.

Comment: @nyaki I have edited your question to better reflect your ideas as expressed in comments. If you are not happy with these changes you can always roll back,,,

Comment: @Cascabel I am ok with it. Though, I have the correct answer I suppose.